# Simple Error - Checked other posts - ngCordova not defined

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova, hybrid

I am facing this error of

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova due to:
```

Now I know this is related to index html not able to reference ngcordova service somehow.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->


<script type="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Now, "lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" is already present. I am very sure it is a simple mistake. But still trying to figure out same.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic-material','ngMessages', 'ngCordova']);
```

Comment: Did you use Bower to install it?

Comment: Initially I used normal, then used bower

Comment: check for your spellings once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: **type** -> **src**

Instead of

```
<script type="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script type="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></scrip‌​t>
```

use

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script‌​>
```

---

Inject **ngCordova** as an Angular dependency in app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```